# dplyr group_by + mutate strange NA appearing

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have a `data.frame` like this

```
datdf  <- structure(list(BM = rep("1907-01-01", 20), 
                         ct = structure(rep(c(1L, 2L), each = 5, times = 2), 
                                        .Label = c("B", "A"), class = "factor"), 
                         val = c(rep(NA, 10), 9901:9910), 
                         facet = rep(c(1, 2), each = 10) ), 
                    row.names = c(NA, -20L), 
                    .Names = c("BM", "ct", "val", "facet"), 
                    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My problem is following. After making some groupwise mutation (I need `cumsum`) I get `NA` values in one of the groups. And it's not only `cumsum` - any modification of `val` throws `NA`.

```
datdf %>% group_by(BM, facet, ct) %>% mutate(v1 = val + 100, v2 = cumsum(val), v3 = val)

#            BM     ct   val facet    v1    v2    v3
#         (chr) (fctr) (int) (dbl) (dbl) (int) (int)
# 11 1907-01-01      B  9901     2 10001  9901  9901
# 12 1907-01-01      B  9902     2 10002 19803  9902
# 13 1907-01-01      B  9903     2 10003 29706  9903
# 14 1907-01-01      B  9904     2 10004 39610  9904
# 15 1907-01-01      B  9905     2 10005 49515  9905
# 16 1907-01-01      A  9906     2    NA    NA  9906
# 17 1907-01-01      A  9907     2    NA    NA  9907
# 18 1907-01-01      A  9908     2    NA    NA  9908
# 19 1907-01-01      A  9909     2    NA    NA  9909
# 20 1907-01-01      A  9910     2    NA    NA  9910
```

My `dplyr` version is 0.4.3, `R` is 3.1.3

Is it a bug or am I missing something? I remember not having this issue with `dplyr 0.4.1` before having updated it some weeks ago.

How can I fix it now?

Comment: One possible fix is to use `data.table` instead. As in ```library(data.table) ; setDT(datdf)[, `:=`(v1 = val + 100, v2 = cumsum(val), v3 = val), by = .(BM, facet, ct)]```

Comment: On a more serious note, I'd guess this should be posted on GH, as it seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I wouldn't consider that a "fix", @David.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I mentioned they should probably post this GH, havn't I?

Comment: One fix might be to try to the [development version](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) of *dplyr*. The results appear reasonable to me using that version.

Comment: thanks to @aosmith, installing development version of `dplyr` helped me without changing the code 
though, I feel growing necessity to get familiar with `data.table` package mentioned by  @DavidArenburg

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use the function `mapvalues` from `plyr` to replace NAs by zeros:

Just for the `v2`(cumsum column):

```
library(plyr)   
datdf %>%  mutate(v1 = val + 100, 
                       v2 = cumsum(val %>% mapvalues(NA, 0)), 
                       v3 = val)
```

Output:

```
           BM     ct   val facet    v1    v2    v3
        (chr) (fctr) (int) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (int)
1  1907-01-01      B    NA     1    NA     0    NA
2  1907-01-01      B    NA     1    NA     0    NA
3  1907-01-01      B    NA     1    NA     0    NA
4  1907-01-01      B    NA     1    NA     0    NA
5  1907-01-01      B    NA     1    NA     0    NA
6  1907-01-01      A    NA     1    NA     0    NA
7  1907-01-01      A    NA     1    NA     0    NA
8  1907-01-01      A    NA     1    NA     0    NA
9  1907-01-01      A    NA     1    NA     0    NA
10 1907-01-01      A    NA     1    NA     0    NA
11 1907-01-01      B  9901     2 10001  9901  9901
12 1907-01-01      B  9902     2 10002 19803  9902
13 1907-01-01      B  9903     2 10003 29706  9903
14 1907-01-01      B  9904     2 10004 39610  9904
15 1907-01-01      B  9905     2 10005 49515  9905
16 1907-01-01      A  9906     2 10006 59421  9906
17 1907-01-01      A  9907     2 10007 69328  9907
18 1907-01-01      A  9908     2 10008 79236  9908
19 1907-01-01      A  9909     2 10009 89145  9909
20 1907-01-01      A  9910     2 10010 99055  9910
```

For all columns:

```
datdf %>%   mutate(v1 = val  %>% mapvalues(NA, 0) + 100, 
                   v2 = cumsum(val %>% mapvalues(NA, 0)), 
                   v3 = val %>% mapvalues(NA, 0))
```

Output:

```
           BM     ct   val facet    v1    v2    v3
        (chr) (fctr) (int) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1  1907-01-01      B    NA     1   100     0     0
2  1907-01-01      B    NA     1   100     0     0
3  1907-01-01      B    NA     1   100     0     0
4  1907-01-01      B    NA     1   100     0     0
5  1907-01-01      B    NA     1   100     0     0
6  1907-01-01      A    NA     1   100     0     0
7  1907-01-01      A    NA     1   100     0     0
8  1907-01-01      A    NA     1   100     0     0
9  1907-01-01      A    NA     1   100     0     0
10 1907-01-01      A    NA     1   100     0     0
11 1907-01-01      B  9901     2 10001  9901  9901
12 1907-01-01      B  9902     2 10002 19803  9902
13 1907-01-01      B  9903     2 10003 29706  9903
14 1907-01-01      B  9904     2 10004 39610  9904
15 1907-01-01      B  9905     2 10005 49515  9905
16 1907-01-01      A  9906     2 10006 59421  9906
17 1907-01-01      A  9907     2 10007 69328  9907
18 1907-01-01      A  9908     2 10008 79236  9908
19 1907-01-01      A  9909     2 10009 89145  9909
20 1907-01-01      A  9910     2 10010 99055  9910
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you ran into some of this issues:
https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1448#issuecomment-150037548

try this:

```
datdf %>% group_by(BM, facet,ct) %>% plyr::mutate(v1 = val + 100, v2 = cumsum(val[!is.na(val)]), v3 = val)

               BM     ct   val facet    v1    v2    v3
            (chr) (fctr) (int) (dbl) (dbl) (int) (int)
    11 1907-01-01      B  9901     2 10001  9901  9901
    12 1907-01-01      B  9902     2 10002 19803  9902
    13 1907-01-01      B  9903     2 10003 29706  9903
    14 1907-01-01      B  9904     2 10004 39610  9904
    15 1907-01-01      B  9905     2 10005 49515  9905
    16 1907-01-01      A  9906     2 10006 59421  9906
    17 1907-01-01      A  9907     2 10007 69328  9907
    18 1907-01-01      A  9908     2 10008 79236  9908
    19 1907-01-01      A  9909     2 10009 89145  9909
    20 1907-01-01      A  9910     2 10010 99055  9910
```

Comment: or from `plyr` try `ddply(datdf, .(BM,facet,ct), mutate, v1=val + 100, v2 = cumsum(val), v3 = val)`